# Blog Site How To Know site Is Computable with AMP or Not

Tags: wordpress, plugins, amp-html

I have wordpress blog Site, install this https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/ Plugin.
and then check my site in https://search.google.com/test/amp this tools in this i simply pest the url of my site this give me error massage "Not an AMP page" now how to know my site is compatible with amp or not.

in mobile view my site open in normal view, it will not open in AMP page View

and also Know to is there any other tools to check my site amp compatible if yes then how to check it means just pest the url on it or anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check AMP status of page :**

See which AMP pages Google can find and crawl on your site, and which pages have errors.

https://search.google.com/test/amp

**How to Setup Google AMP in WordPress**

Thankfully it is a lot easier now to implement Google AMP in WordPress than it was 6 months ago. A lot of progress has been made on WordPress plugins and the platform as a whole. Remember though, your code must validate with Google to show the AMP version of your site in SERPs. A plugin will turn your post into an AMP version but it is Google that decides to show the AMP version instead.

Basically how it works is that your WordPress post gets a different URL assigned to it. This is all handled by the WordPress plugin automatically. Typically /amp or /?amp is appended to your current post. Here is an example:

Original Blog Post URL: https://example.com/blog-post
AMP Blog Post URL: https://example.com/blog-post/amp/

Complete Blog : https://kinsta.com/blog/google-amp/